# Artificially populate HttpContext object in a Console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

I am writing a wrapper library for log4net. This library should be able to capture Context information such as querystring, cookie, form fields etc. etc.

I am invoking this wrapper class from Console application as opposed to TDD class.

Is there a way to populate HttpContext object inside a Console application as follows?

```
HttpContext c = new HttpContext(null);
c.Request.QueryString.Keys[1] = "city";
c.Request.QueryString[1] = "Los Angeles";
c.Request.QueryString.Keys[2] = "state";
c.Request.QueryString[2] = "CA";
```

And then retrieve it as follows?

```
Console.WriteLine(context.Request.QueryString.Keys[1]);
```

I am getting the following exception when I attempt the above code.

```
Property or indexer 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Comment: why on earth are you depending on httpcontext within a console app? what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Adreas, just edited my question to address your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read here on using Moq to fake it out: 
http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/mocking-httpcontext-httprequest-and-httpresponse-for-unittests-using-moq/

Answer (score 1):

It's not easily possible to mock a HttpContext. You could use [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product3) to setup the context but its not free. Another (better) approach would be to abstract the HttpContext and implement your console (test?) client against a mock implementation of the abstraction